# Single Global Variables for multiple client requests using JSP

Tags: jsp

I am developing a custom search application. The query input by the user is to be pre-processed to remove certain query terms. The criteria for removal is based on a score that has been pre-computed for all the terms in the corpus. I am thinking of storing the terms and their scores in a hash and when the user inputs a query, I can get the scores of the terms from the hash and remove the terms depending upon the criteria.

However, since the hash is very big, is it possible to have it as a global variable such that for multiple client requests only a single copy of the variable is in the memory? I guess that declaring it as a global variable in `index.jsp` will not work because for every client request a separate copy will be created in the memory.

Comment: Your question implies that you are going to be developing a multi-layered application that will utilize caching to improve performance.  When apps start going down more complex design roads, its better to begin using frameworks that a) include standard patterns you can follow to ease your development and maintenance, and b) include functionality you would otherwise need to hand-code yourself (such as caching).  You could just use servlets and JSP, but then you would need to reinvent the wheel over and over again.

Answer (score 2):

You could store it in the [application scope](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29).

```
application.setAttribute("someName", someObject);
```

You can get it again by `getAttribute()`.

---

Note that this job is normally to be done by a `ServletContextListener` and/or a `HttpServlet`, not inside a JSP. Writing Java code in JSPs is considered poor practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Singleton pattern. It will initiate only once.